# HDMI monitor not working simultaneously with laptop monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, xrandr, lspci

My Toshiba Satellite laptop is dual boot. Both the HDMI (LG FLATRON L1710B) and Laptop monitor work simultaneously in Windows automatically without any configuration.

[Both work in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHDB7.png)

Release information is as follows:

```
~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```

The version of Ubuntu installed on the Toshiba Satellite laptop.

```
$ uname -a
Linux SATELLITE-L50D-B 5.3.0-51-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 22 21:09:44 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have connected an external monitor screen connected to the laptop through the HDMI laptop's output. The external monitor only works in Ubuntu when I go into the BIOS and select HDMI. However the laptop monitor does not work simultaneously.
The laptop internal monitor only works in Ubuntu when I go into the BIOS and select System Monitor. However the HDMI monitor does not work simultaneously.

This is the output of the xrandr command when the HDMI is enabled in the BIOS:

```
wasadmin@SATELLITE-L50D-B:~$ xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1280 x 1024, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024     77.00*
wasadmin@SATELLITE-L50D-B:~$
```

This is the output of the xrandr command when the system monitor is enabled in the BIOS:

```
wasadmin@SATELLITE-L50D-B:/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d$ xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1366 x 768, current 1366 x 768, maximum 1366 x 768
default connected 1366x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1366x768      76.00*
```

I cannot see any HDMI in the output even when the HDMI BIOS is enabled
in the BIOS. Can you help?

Comment: Which Linux have you installed and what is its release number? You have shown us the kernel, not the distribution, which we need ot know. Please click [edit] to add that vital information. Please do not use Add Comment; all information needed to solve the problem should be in the Question, put there with [edit].

Comment: xrandr shows, that the X-Server does not recognize the second monitor. It seems to be a monitor problem, not related to graphics card or driver. Please provide the monitor you're using

Comment: Hi @kanehekili,
Thanks for responding. Both my WINDOWS and Ubuntu can send a display signal to the LG monitor via an HDMI cable.
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue in the past but in a different direction. when you get

```
Failed to get size of gamma for output default Screen
```

The issue is that you don't have the correct drivers, this especially happens on older integrated graphics and newer amd ones. This should go away with the correct drivers.